# Why it shows Hide details?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why is it showing Hide details ? The name is true

```
let name=true;
const template= (
      <div>
         <h1>Visibility Toggle</h1>
         <button >{name==true ? 'Show details': 'Hide details'}</button>
         <p></p>
      </div>
);

const appRoot=document.getElementById('app');

ReactDOM.render(template,appRoot);
```

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log` name to make sure it is true. If it is in fact true then yes 'Show details' should show

Comment: Also, comparing things to `true` or `false` with `==` is very dangerous in JS. (Many say using `==` *at all* is dangerous and should be avoided - I don't agree, but there are definitely some pitfalls to be aware of, and this is the biggest one.) Note in particular that `name == true` does *not* test if `name` is truthy or falsy - to do that you should just use the much simpler `name` as the test in your ternary operator.

Comment: I'm assuming this isn't the full example, and your problem occurs somewhere in your logic. You can try to `console.log` the value of `name` and try to find the culprit.
Also, avoid component names starting with a small letter, as you won't be able to use them inside JSX expressions without rebinding them to variables starting with a capital letter.

Comment: On what kind of environment are you trying this?

Comment: I changed it to:        name ? 'Show details': 'Hide details'

Comment: @Szymon Did this work for you?

Comment: but when i changed name to false it is still showing "Show Details"

Comment: Then it seems there's problems in your logic setting name to true. Can you show more of your code or is that all of it? The above code should work.

Comment: Also if you set your statement to `true ? 'Show details': 'Hide details'` is it correct? Because that absolutely should show you the correct result

Comment: willing to guess you have a string and not a Boolean.

Comment: @BradeyWhitlock this is why I've asked the environment :) It is a weird issue. I can't reproduce it with my local tools or any decent online React site but if you try this with Stackoverflow's answer code snippet you can reproduce it. I'm confused, too.

Comment: Is the code in your question, the actual code you are using?

Comment: Yes. This is my code. But in JavaScript variables have automatically adjusted type